# Android Activity appears on top when I'm using another app

Tags: android

I have a long running operation. Inside a thread I start a new activity like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                 }
             });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

The problem is when I run another app and the thread finishes, that activity appears on the top of the screen. How to force that activity not to apear on the top?

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));` Why do you start your current activty again?

Comment: It's an example. In a real case I start another one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like below..

```
Handler splashHandler;
splashHandler = new Handler();

 splashHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
                finish();

        }
    }, 2000);



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (splashHandler != null)
        splashHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (splashHandler != null)
        splashHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're getting the Context out of the "other app". You should pass in the application context rather than a context from the local activity. Use context.getApplicationContext() and save that in a local variable, then use this context to start the activity

The code should be something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<VideoDataDescription> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    MainActivity.progressDialog.dismiss();

    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
}
```

}

you'd call it like this:

```
   new MyTask(context).execute();
```